# user not being associated with ldap group membership by id <username>

Tags: ldap, pam, centos6.4, posix

I have an existing set of Centos 5.4 servers that restrict login based on being a uniquemember of an ldap group vizusers.  The users can be a direct uniquemember of the group or be a member of a group that is a uniquemember of `vizusers`.

I am trying to implement this same method under Centos 6.4.  The ldap server is on a closed network and does not support SSL or TLS so sssd is not possible.  Using `pam_ldap` and `nslcd` is required.

Users that are direct uniquemembers resolve correctly as evidenced by "groups username" returning vizusers as a secondary group.  Users that should inherit this group return only their primary group.

`pam_ldap.conf`, `ldap.conf` and `nslcd.conf` do not vary from the working configuration on the Centos 5.4 hosts.

ldapsearch of vizusers returns all the users and groups that are uniquemembers.  A subsequent search of subgroups, correctly returns the expected users.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to [answer of stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47645/group-within-group-file-permissions) there is not such a thing like "linux nested groups".

So behaviour of Centos 6.4 is as expected.

How did it work on Centos 5.4 is a mistery.

Sidenote: in my opinion `sssd` can work fine with plaintext LDAP binding.